# number of combination with grid and design

Tags: combinatorics

> On a grid  starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(20,12)$, how many path passes through both the points $(10,5)$ and $(12,8)$?

I have thought - the number of path from $(0,0)$ to $(10,5)$ is $ \frac{(10+5)!}{10 ! \ 5!}$  and the find the number of path from $(10,5)$ to $(12,8)$ and multiply them but I can not find the number of path from $(10,5)$ to $(12,8)$.

Please help me.

Comment: Need to know: do the paths need to go only to right or up?

Comment: both right and up

Comment: Then can do from (10,5) to (12,8) same as (0,0) to (2,3).

Comment: many many thanks

Comment: They are often descibed as "minimal paths".

Answer (score 0):

We have a few fixed points on our path, so as you stated, we can just find out how many paths there are between these points and then multiply those answers together. To get from $(0,0)$ to $(10,5)$, there are $15 \choose 5$ paths, as we have to choose 5 ups out of 15 steps. To get from $(10,5)$ to $(12,8)$, there would be $5 \choose 2$ paths, as there are 5 steps total and 2 of them in a certain direction. Finally to get from $(12,8)$ to $(20,12)$, we have $12\choose 4$ possibilities, since we have 12 steps total and 4 of them are in a certain direction. Thus, our answer is $15 \choose 5$$5 \choose 2$$12\choose 4$$=14864850$